# Robocopy Blow Away and Recreate?

Tags: robocopy

I have a question about ROBOCOPY which I have not been able to iron out in my research.

When copying directories recursively with the /E flag and where the directory already exists at the target, does ROBOCOPY:

1. delete the existing directory and re-create it? or
2. ascertain that the directory already exists, and continue with its work using the existing directory.

I think the answer is 2, but would like to be sure, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robocopy will reuse the directory found on the destination. If copying security information as well, it will then apply the correct ACL settings to the directory. The same for owner information.